# swift ui handle property changed in observableObject

Tags: swift, swiftui

so - I have a text field on a screen - the data loads asynchronously - so I've created and ObservableObject with a published field, and successfully bind it to the view:

```swift
class Blah : ObservableObject
{
    @Published var value : Double? = nil
 
    init()
    { 
         load_variable_async().then {result in self.value = result }
    }
}
```

which works perfectly - the view reflects the value of the variable and everything.
But - I want it to work both ways.      Published *seems* to be a bidirectional wrapper, so I want to add something like this:

```swift
init()
{
    load_variable_async().then {result in self.value = result }
    value.when_changed { new_value in asynchronously_save( variable) }
}
```

and I can't find any way of doing it.  Everything I google for puts a sink or some call to a save in *the view* - which seems completely wrong to me... if I'm reading it in one place, I want to be writing it in the same place -  and if I'm already binding the variable to a textfield for instance, and bindings go both ways, then enough connections have already been made

So what am I doing wrong?  How do react to value being set, inside my "model" object without explicitly putting some sort of save or other action into the view?

Comment: So, you want text field in your view to update when published property changes in model, am I right?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with your second example, except that you're using a bunch of wrappers like `asynchronously_save` that aren't clear what they're doing -- maybe they're the cause of the issue you're experiencing? Can you come up with a [mre] that illustrates the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution I wanted - the binding from model -> textfield was always working, but the value from textfield -> model I couldn't get working.  The magic seems to be this keyword "willSet"

```swift
   @Published var value : Double? = nil {
       willSet( new_value ) {
             print("going to save asynchronously now")
       }}
```

works magically.